# ContentPresenter issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ContentControl on which I have a grid. Column 1 will be a TreeView, Column 2 is a splitter and I have set column 3 to be a ContentPresenter. Defined as such:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Name="PlaceHolder" />
```

If I then add my ContentControl to a Page and add an item to the ContentControl it does not just appear in column 2 but instead spans the entire width of the ContentControl. This is how I add something to the ContentPresenter:

```
<MyNamespace:MyControlName>
    <Button>Hello world!</Button>
</MyNamespace:MyControlName>
```

How can I get the button to only appear in column 2 and have the TreeView in column 0 appear as normal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the full XAML of the contentcontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your `ContentControl.Content` property in the `ContentControl` to your `Grid`, then when you use the control you are overwriting `ContentControl.Content` to set it as a `Button` instead

You need to set your `Grid` to be the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` instead of the actual `Content`, and modify your `ContentPresenter` show the `Content` property

```
<ContentControl ...>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Grid>
                ...
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Name="PlaceHolder" 
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                ...
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Tried that, the button still expands to fill the entire width of the ContentControl

Comment: @RobertLancaster See my revised answer based on the XAML you posted

Comment: tried that too ... now there is nothing displayed in my ContentControl at all.

Comment: @RobertLancaster Did you include the `ContentPresenter.Content` binding? You need to tell it that to host the content supplied there with `{TemplateBinding Content}`

Comment: Does the code you have here above go inside the <Grid> element or does it wrap it?

Comment: @RobertLancaster It goes around the Grid (see updated answer). You need to set the `Grid` as your `ContentTemplate` instead of the `Content` to avoid having the content you specify when using the control overwrite it.